# context.hasRole is not a function in Nodejs sinon testing issue

Tags: node.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I had made function to fetch cloudwatch details from AWS.I trying to create a testcase in node.js and using sinon but i am getting a context.hasRole is  not defined because i am checking this in my function file which is cloudwatch.js.
Can you please help me to fake this test

```
"-----cloudwatch.spec.js-------"
describe('cloudwatch', () => {
    let sandbox = null;

beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox(AWS.config);
})

afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore()
})


it('Should return queryid', async () => {
    let queryId = {
        queryId: "12ab3456-12ab-123a-789e-1234567890ab"
    };
    const body = {
        endTime: 34568765,
        queryString: 'filter @message like /Audit/',
        startTime: 34565678,
        limit: 100,
        logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/dev-api--service-sandbox-api'
    };
    let params = {}
    let queryid = {
        queryId: 6786971301298309123
    };
    await cloudwatch.startQuery(context, params, body, callback);
    sinon.match(queryId)
 })
 })


"------Cloudwatch.js----"
let cloudwatch = module.exports = {};
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const nconf = require('nconf');
const {
  HttpResult,
  HttpUnauthorizedError,
  AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient
       } = require('api-lib');

  AWS.config = nconf.get('amazonCloudWatchLogsClient');

  cloudwatch.startQuery = async function(context, params, body, 
  callback) {
  body.startTime = new Date(body.startTime).valueOf();
  body.endTime = new Date(body.endTime).valueOf();
  if (!context.hasRole("read:cloudwatch"))
    return callback(new HttpUnauthorizedError("context missing role 
                    read:cloudwatch"));
  const amazonCloudWatchLogsClient = new 
  AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(AWS.config);
  let result = await amazonCloudWatchLogsClient.startQuery(body, 
  function(err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
  });
  callback(null, new HttpResult(result));
  };

  cloudwatch.getQueryResults = async function(context, params, 
  requestBody, callback) {
  console.log(requestBody)
  let test = requestBody.queryId;
  test = test.toString();
  requestBody.queryId = test;
  if (!context.hasRole("read:cloudwatch"))
    return callback(new HttpUnauthorizedError("context missing role 
   read:cloudwatch"));
  const amazonCloudWatchLogsClient = new 
  AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(AWS.config);
  let result2 = await 
  amazonCloudWatchLogsClient.getQueryResults(requestBody.queryId, 
  function(err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  });
  callback(null, new HttpResult(result2));
  };
```

I am using eslint and except from chai for comparing the output to the sample output.

Comment: Please provide the code under test

Comment: Provided the code for cloudwatch.js